# JavaScript API To Start Login Flow For New Sign In With Google Library

Tags: google-signin

I'm trying to use the new Google Sign-in library following the guides and API docs [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference).

However the default sign-in button doesn't fit well with my website, so I'm trying to create my own themed button and then start the sign-in flow when the user clicks it. My problem is I can't find a JS API in the Google Sign In lib I can call to start the JS flow. I see in the previous version of the SDK such a function exists, does it not exist in the new lib?

Answer (score 0):

By design the button icon, theme, size, text and shape can be customized using a set of predefined [attributes](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#attribute_types). These have been standardized for our users -- consistent look-n-feel and uniform sign-up and sign-in behavior improve recognition and trust.

The new library does not offer the ability to customize the button or user flows, OAuth2 and OpenID endpoints remain an option if it is necessary to customize beyond what is supported in the attributes. It would be helpful to hear more details on how the attributes do not fit your needs: height, width, color, wording, etc.